# Parent ViewModel to share variables with child ViewModels and LiveData

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata, subscribe

In my Android application I have a single Main Activity with a navigation drawer and a spinner. The spinner contains a list of years.

Main activity and each of the fragments have their own viewModel.

In MainActivityViewModel I have a MutableLiveData which is changed when spinner item is selected.

How could I subscribe to changes in spinner from other viewmodels different from MainActivityViewModel ?

Comment: just use the same viewmodel in activity and fragments

Comment: That's an option. The main issue here is that I'll end up having a huge viewModel. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: I think there is no point of storing `MutableLiveData` in `MainActivityViewModel`. Maybe you can put it inside the repository so that any `viewModel` can subscribe to it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm used to seeing LiveData in ViewModels, but it makes sense to have it in repository as it is accessible from any viewmodel.